# Can't modify query variables in dialog Query CRM Data step

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to query all the members of the team that owns a particular case. Here's a screenshot of the query I built:

[image: Query Builder]

This works fine and returns the users that belong to the team that owns the case called "Mike Test". However, when I switch to the Modify Query Variables tab and try to make the "Mike Test" entry dynamic based on the case the dialog is running against I don't get the text box to replace the hardcoded value like I normally do.

[image: Modify Query Variables]

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can only modify query variable for fields on the entity you're querying, not on related entities.

Comment: I have the same problem? How did you solve your problem?

Comment: I don't remember to be honest, sorry. It was probably some terribly hacky workaround though.